# Python __init__ finding variable from nowhere

Tags: python

I'm really struggling to understand how this behavior is emerging. I've boiled it down to as small an example as possible which still produces the undesired effect.

- I initialise an instance of a class, whose initiator specificies that if an optional argument is not passed, it should be an empty list.
- I then add some data via a method on the class which should be acting as an instance method.
- I create a new instance of the same class, again without passing a variable to the initiator, but this time the variable is populated as if by magic.

Code:

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, x=[]):
        self._x = x
        print x

    def add_x(self, data):
        self._x.append(data)

for x in range(0, 5):
    obj = Demo()
    obj.add_x([1, 2])
```

Output:

```
[]
[[1, 2]]
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) and [this effbot article](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I did try googling for it but I couldn't find anything. I was getting increasingly and increasingly confident that I'd found something major

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, x=[]):
    self._x = x
```

In this case, whenever you initialize an instance of your class with no argument, self._x will reference the same object instead of creating a new empty list for each instance. In effect, `self._x.append` is appending to the same list.

The recommended way to do this is

```
def __init__(self, x=None):
    if x is None:
        # create a new list
        x = []
    self._x = x
```

This applies to all mutable objects (such as `dict` and `set`...).

Answer (score 1):

In Python if you use `a = b` then it doesn't creates a new object instead both point to the **same** memory location, And we know that lists are mutable so any changes made would be reflected in all the references to that memory location. Now you can use `[:]` if you have a linear list or you can also use `deepcopy()` in case there are nested lists.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x=list()):
        self._x = x[:]    #Here is the magic
        print x

    def add_x(self, data):
        self._x.append(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but why is this the default behaviour? Is there anywhere I can read up on this?